# semantic-ui search following link when pressing 'enter'

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I want to allow users to navigate the search tool only with the keyboard which means that they navigate search results with arrows and, when they press 'enter', it follows the item's link.

How could this be done ?

[Here is an example from the docs, with a GitHub search box](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#using-different-response-fields)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui.search')
      .search({
        apiSettings: {
          url: /?q={query}'
        },
        fields: {
            results : 'items',
            title   : 'name',
            actionUrl: 'url'
        },
        minCharacters : 3,
        onSelect(result, response){ <-- here
            window.location.href = result.url;  
        }
      })
    ;
```